# Por que ponteiros têm tamanho fixo independente do tipo apontado?

Tags: c

O espaço ocupado por váriaveis normais (`int`, `float`, `double`, `char`) obedece a regra de tipo: `int` ocupa 4 bytes, `float` ocupa 4 bytes, `double` ocupa 8 bytes etc.

Por que ponteiros de diferentes tipo têm exatamente o mesmo tamanho em bytes (4 bytes dependendo da arquitetura do seu computador) independente do tipo de ponteiro?

Comment: Máquina 32 bits tem ponteiros de 32 bits. Máquina 64 bits tem ponteiros 64 bits. Máquinas 16 bits anciãs (ou controladores PIC) tem ponteiros de 16 bits. Independente do tipo apontado

Comment: Existem contextos em que `int` é 16 bits, principalmente para controladores e para máquinas antigas. Por mais que sejam raros esses contextos, eles existem

Answer (score 8):

Porque um ponteiro contém um endereço de memória, e todos os endereços de memória têm o mesmo tamanho.

Por exemplo, imagine que a memória do computador seja parecida com uma rua com várias casas lado a lado, numeradas como 0, 1, 2, 3... (e sim, elas começam no zero). Cada uma dessas casas armazena um byte na memória. Além disso, você pode se referir a cada uma dessas casas por seu endereço. Para representar o endereço de uma dessas casas, basta o número da casa, afinal de contas, só existe uma única rua neste caso.

Se você estiver em uma arquitetura de 32 bits (32 bits = 4 bytes), então a última casa da rua seria aquela de número 4.294.967.295, número esse que corresponde a **2<sup>32</sup> - 1**. Isso daí é o mesmo que 4 Gb. Assim sendo, para representar um endereço de memória qualquer (memória até 4 Gb), você vai precisar de endereços com 4 bytes.

Observe, enfim, que não importa qual é o tipo de dado que você armazena nessas casinhas, você continua precisando de um mesmo número de bytes para representar um endereço. Um ponteiro para `float` nada mais é do que algum lugar na memória de onde você quer ler ou escrever um `float`, e um ponteiro para `int` é um lugar de onde você quer ler ou escrever um `int`. Independente do que você quer ler ou escrever, as casinhas referenciadas são as mesmas e estão na mesma rua, e portanto têm endereços do mesmo tipo.

4 Gb de memória no máximo é insuficiente para os computadores mais modernos. Por isso, em arquiteturas de 64 bits, os endereços têm 8 bytes. Isso é teoricamente o suficiente para 8 [exbibytes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exbibyte). Mas obviamente, na prática não existe computadores com tanta memória assim e estamos muito longe de ter. Entretanto, se você precisar de qualquer coisa com mais de 4 Gb de memória, a arquitetura de 64 bits é praticamente obrigatória.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua explicação. Gostei muito.

Answer (score 5):

Porque um ponteiro guarda em si um *endereço de memória*, e estes têm todos o mesmo tamanho independente do tipo de dados com o qual se deve interpretar o objeto naquele endereço.

Numa plataforma de 32 bits, os endereços de memória têm 32 bits, então os ponteiros todos têm este tamanho. Numa plataforma de 64 bits, os endereços de memória terão eventualmente 64 bits, então os ponteiros já têm essa largura para caber os endereços necessários para quando os computadores tiverem mais que 1 TiB de memória principal...

Answer (score 4):

Ponteiros tem sempre o mesmo tamanho independente do tipo de dado porque guardam o endereço da posição onde a variável começa. E este endereço tem tamanho fixo de acordo com a arquitetura em questão.

Comment: Valew cara. Muito obrigado