# Tamanho de uma array dinamica

Tags: c, arduino

Estou fazendo teste com alocação dinamica de memória, mas quando tento obter o tamanho do array sempre tenho o mesmo resultado.

```
int main()
{
    int *teste=malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    int len=sizeof(teste) / sizeof(int);

    print("%i\n", len);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilando com gcc:

```
bash-4.2$ ./teste
2
```

Não importa se coloco `sizeof(int) * 100` ou `10`, sempre retorna 2 :(
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Acredito que é porque você está calculando o tamanho de um ponteiro, não de um *array*. [Por que ponteiros têm tamanho fixo independente do tipo apontado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216698/5878)

Comment: Acho que pode ser isso mesmo, mas ai surge outra pergunta..
como obter o tamanho de uma array dinâmica, preciso fazer uma estrutura ou outro local pra guardar o tamanho?

Answer (score 1):

A idiomática `sizeof(teste) / sizeof(int)` é capaz apenas de calcular o tamanho de em bytes de buffers alocados estaticamente:

```
int teste[ 123 ];
printf("%d\n", sizeof(teste) / sizeof(int) ); /* 492 / 4 = 123 */
```

No seu caso, `teste` é um ponteiro para uma região de memória alocada dinamicamente e `sizeof(teste)` é o tamanho em bytes que esse ponteiro ocupa, e não o tamanho da memória para qual ele está apontando.

```
int * teste = NULL;
printf("%d\n", sizeof(teste) / sizeof(int) ); /* 8 / 4 = 2 */
```

Que tal:

```
int main()
{
    int len = sizeof(int) * 10;
    int *teste=malloc(len);

    print("%d\n", len); /* 40 */

    free(teste);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelas colaborações, no seu exemplo **Lacobus** no meu projeto não daria certo porque não sei o tamanho da array ao criar e sempre vou realocando (realloc) mas lembrei de algo que pode ser feito, lá das aulas de estrutura de dados.

Eu fiz uma estrutura

```
struct __buf {
   int *ptr;
   int len;
};
```

Na medida que vou ajustando o tamanho da array eu atualizo a estrutura, assim:

```
__buf buffer_serial;
...
buffer_serial.ptr = malloc ( sizeof(int) * len);
buffer_seria.len = len;
...
```

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, fdavid , mas isso é basicamente a aplicação da resposta do colega @Lacobus, que é salvar o tamanho numa variável.